How to snap an object to a grid?
I am trying to emulate something like Factorio's train system and a core component involves placing rails. One of the game's mechanics has objects snapping to a grid. Another example would be Fortnite and how it snaps its build objects to a grid as well.
I want to have a UI that I can select rails, for example, from and then place them on a grid instead of arbitrary positions.
